# Oracle NoSQL Cloud Service - Is it possible to do a connection using instance-principal instead of creating config files?

Tags: oracle-nosql

I am using Oracle NoSQL Cloud Service on OCI and I want to write a program using the Oracle NoSQL Database Python SDK.

I did a test using the OCI SDK, I am using instance-principal IAM vs creating config files with tenancy/user ocid and API private keys on the nodes which invoke the noSQL api calls

Is it possible to do a connection using instance-principal instead of creating config files with tenancy/user ocid and API private keys with the Oracle NoSQL Database Python SDK.

I read the examples provided in the documentation https://github.com/oracle/nosql-python-sdk but I cannot find information about instance-principal support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oracle NoSQL Database Python SDK works with instance-principals and resource principals. See the documentation https://nosql-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/borneo.iam.SignatureProvider.html

Here an example using resource principals and Oracle functions

```
def get_handle():
provider = borneo.iam.SignatureProvider.create_with_resource_principal()
compartment_id = provider.get_resource_principal_claim(borneo.ResourcePrincipalClaimKeys.COMPARTMENT_ID_CLAIM_KEY)


config = borneo.NoSQLHandleConfig(os.getenv('NOSQL_REGION'), provider).set_logger(None).set_default_compartment(compartment_id)
return borneo.NoSQLHandle(config)
```